# svn diff last committed and last branched

Tags: svn, branch, diff

I have created a branch and I have made a couple of commits.
I would like to see diff between last committed revision and version when the file was branched.

Can svn do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a command line option there are two scenarios.

1. Diff the branch to the trunk.  Very straightforward, but the trunk may have been updated

   svn diff $REPOSITORY/trunk $REPOSITORY/branches/my-branch
2. Only diff the changes in the branch.  I have not found a simple way to do this yet, so I parse out the branch creation revision from the logs

   svn diff -r`svn log -v -r0:HEAD --stop-on-copy --limit 1 | grep r[0-9] | sed 's/r([0-9]*)\ .*/\1/g'` $REPOSITORY/branches/my-branch